# Cut hole in plane using hollow object?

Tags: modifiers, bisect

I'm trying to place a boat on top of a plane and not have the plane show up within the boat, how can I achieve this?

You can see what I mean below.  I want the "water" to end at the edge of the boat so it doesn't seem like it's filled with water.

I'm using Blender 3.0.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Hi :). You can use one of the horizontal edges and use Knife Project to cut a hole into the plane

Comment: If you need it in a non-destructive way so that you can move the boat around, why not add a second boat (just the outline, no detailed model) closed at the top so that's a filled object. Parent it to the original boat, make it invisble in viewport and render and use it as cutting object for the plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the plane a solidify modifier and then you can use the boolean modifier. The thickness could be very low, so you don't even recognize it. But the boolean modifier needs some "volume" so that it works correctly. It doesn't work with a plane.

Like this:

[image]